# Internet Explorer 9 Displaying buttons differently than IE10, Firefox & Safari ect

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

im having some trouble with my website

```
<a href="#" class="button">read more</a></div>
```

This code displays a rounded blue button:

picture of what it looks like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQR5r.png

I cant seem to figure out why. 
i moved my website pages (for example contact.html about.html ) to individual folders and named them all index.html so when the URL loads it doesnt show www.websitename.com/contact.html, it now shows www.websitename.com/contact.
but ever since, the below issue is happening.
everything else is fine, all other things load fine, just this specific button.

This is the CSS behind the button:

```
.text .button {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:53px;
    padding:0 37px;
    background:url(../images/button_bg.gif) top repeat-x #308da2;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    behavior:url(../js/PIE.htc);
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

your help would be much appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Did you clear you cache on all the browsers?

Comment: yes cache cleared, same result

Answer (score 0):

please insert demo or jsfiddle.net link, in this way we will have access to your resources. but have you inserted this code?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: I tried the <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">  and no difference has been made